# RemoteObject method return value

Tags: java, rmi, remoteobject

Does a RemoteObject method's return object has to be a serializable?
For example, A is a remote object and has the function:

```
SomeObject getMyObject() throws java.rmi.RemoteException
```

does SomeObject have to be serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well according to the docs it should be:

> 2.6    Parameter Passing in Remote Method Invocation
>
> An argument to, or **a return value** from, a remote object can be **any
>   object that is serializable**. **This includes *primitive types*, *remote
>   objects*, and *non-remote objects* that implement the
>   *java.io.Serializable interface***. For more details on how to make
>   classes serializable, see the "Java Object Serialization
>   Specification." Classes, for parameters or return values, that are not
>   available locally are downloaded dynamically by the RMI system. See
>   the section on "Dynamic Class Loading" for more information on how RMI
>   downloads parameter and return value classes when reading parameters,
>   return values and exceptions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/spec/rmi-objmodel7.html

And this makes sense. The Object should transmitted from one node to the other. In order to be transmitted, it should be placed in a socket (at some point), so it should serialized.

Comment: Does that include primitive types? I mean, do primitive types actually implement java.io.serializable?

Comment: Primitive types are serializable, in that the JVM knows how to convert them into a stream of bits, but they cannot implement any interface, since they are not Objects.

Comment: Note that the quotation doesn't say it must be Serializable. It says it must be 'any object that is *serializable.*` It isn't the same thing, as the quotation goes on to make clear.

Answer (score 1):

It must either be a primitive type, a Serializable type, or an exported remote object itself. In the latter case it is automatically converted to a Stub. `Registry.lookup()` is an example.